# Best way to speed up reading text file to sql table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I know this question is asked many times, but my question is a slightly different one:

My requirement is as follows:

I have a text file with approx. 50000 lines and the file is almost 10 mb.

Each line has values with a fixed size as below:

```
0001            abcdefgh          1234567         xyz
0002            pqrst             02233           abc
003             asddfd            545             slfkk
```

its not a tab separated or comma separated etc.

I have a sql table with the same structure as below:

```
code varchar(5)
name varchar(18)
phone varchar(16)
address varchar(20)
```

What I have to accomplish is that when the customer clicks the button, it should empty the sql table and read the new records from the text file (As this is an ASP.net application, I am using WCF services to read the file and pass the string to the server and its working fine).

The code for splitting  and saving to the database is as follows:

```
       Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
       string data = client.ReadFile(@"C:\testfolder\test.txt");


        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM table1");

       table1 c;


        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(data))
        {
            string line = "";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                c = new table1();
                c.Code = line.Substring(0, 5).Trim();
                c.name= line.Substring(5, 18).Trim();
                c.phone= line.Substring(23, 16).Trim();
                c.address = line.Substring(39, 20).Trim();
                context.table1.Add(c);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    client.Close();
```

but this approach takes at least 30 minutes to copy all the records. is there any better way to speed this?

thanks

Comment: And use SqlBulkCopy. I bet no time is used reading - only seconds. Thew time is used in table1.Add (AddRows gets slow with many rows) and the SaveChanges (10.000 inserts), NOT in the reading loop.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that it is already in memory.  I do agree on the bulk insert though

Comment: What he can do is run a performance analysis on that block of code to determine where the performance bottleneck is and then report to us where and we can attempt to optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a database head I was going to say "BCP" but ... use SqlBulkCopy. See article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ek5da1a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

"Microsoft SQL Server includes a popular command-line utility named bcp for quickly bulk copying large files into tables or views in SQL Server databases. The SqlBulkCopy class allows you to write managed code solutions that provide similar functionality. There are other ways to load data into a SQL Server table (INSERT statements, for example) but SqlBulkCopy offers a significant performance advantage over them."

Comment: You are correct! SqlBulkCopy is the way to go... its taking only less than 5 seconds to do the entire process!! Thanks so much

Comment: :-) glad to be of help. been there myself.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file isn't what is taking time, it's the insert into the DB.
I would modify it in the following manner, instead of performing the update all at once do it in smaller batches:

You can test the performance by changing the `if` statement for how many rows you insert into a batch.

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(data))
    {
        string line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            c = new table1();
            c.Code = line.Substring(0, 5).Trim();
            c.name= line.Substring(5, 18).Trim();
            c.phone= line.Substring(23, 16).Trim();
            c.address = line.Substring(39, 20).Trim();
            context.table1.Add(c);
            if (counter == 10){
              context.SaveChanges();
              counter =0;
           }
           else{
              counter++;
           }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Alternatively, you could design a `producer/consumer` model where the file is read independently of the DB inserts, so in essence you would have 2 threads running, 1 thread reading and the other inserting into DB.  Making more than 1 thread inserting into DB would not help however reading independently of the DB insert may improve the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading one line at a time, which is extremely inefficient. You should use BufferedStream instead:

> A buffer is a block of bytes in memory used to cache data, thereby
>   reducing the number of calls to the operating system. Buffers improve
>   read and write performance. A buffer can be used for either reading or
>   writing, but never both simultaneously. The Read and Write methods of
>   BufferedStream automatically maintain the buffer.

Comment: In our case, we need to read exactly one line of data as it is a claims row or EDI row. The buffer or block of bytes may be difficult for jagged record lengths. Okay for identical record lengths. Yes, one line at a time is necessary from this viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Do intermediary SaveChanges and replace your context by a new one:

```
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    int lines = 0;
    int batchSize=50;
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(data))
    {
        string line = "";

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            c = new table1();
            c.Code = line.Substring(0, 5).Trim();
            c.name= line.Substring(5, 18).Trim();
            c.phone= line.Substring(23, 16).Trim();
            c.address = line.Substring(39, 20).Trim();
            context.table1.Add(c);

            if (lines++ % batchSize == 0)
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                context = new DataContext();
                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

You can adjust the batchSize

Comment: other than possibly re-connecting to the DB what does creating a new context do for you?  That to me seems unnecessary.

Comment: @TMcKeown It frees memory used by the context. Why ? I do not know, but it is what I have observed.

Comment: hmmm, interesting.  my only concern would be the potential reconnection time it may use.  definitely something to test/measure.